# MySQL Bulk Insert of Geometry fields

Tags: mysql, geometry, bulkinsert

I have a mysql database that I'm trying to populate from a text file. The contents of my file look like (as just some examples. there are thousands of rows)

```
1:GeomFromText('Polygon(0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 0 0)')
2:GeomFromText('Polygon(0 0, 1 2, 2 2, 0 0)')
```

In my schema, the first field is an integer and the second is GEOMETRY

I try to load the data

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt' INTO TABLE `testDb`.`testTable` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

And I get the error

```
Error Code 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

If I try to do an individual insert like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE testTable(id,region) VALUES (1,GeomFromText('Polygon(0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 0 0)'))
```

It works with no problems. This is very inefficient for a large number of inserts though. Does anyone know why the bulk load is throwing that error?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Why don't you write a very simple script in bash or php or something that will perform all the inserts while going through the file. Even AWK could do this quite well I would think.

Comment: It's several hundred thousand inserts, which is really slow in database terms.

Comment: @Scott. there were actually some other slow downs. now the insert with looping over only takes about 4 minutes, so that works for our case. thanks.

Comment: too localized -- you're trying to evaluate SQL/MM in the load rather than WKT. Likely to confuse search engines and lots of people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bulk insert does not evaluate sql statements, it just places the values into the db. That means that *GeomFromText('Polygon(0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 0 0)')* is interpreted as just a string value, which is not a Geometry object, and hence cannot be inserted into a Geometry column.

You need to set a function to be called on each row insert like below where *emphasized text* **obj_id** and **obj_geo** are the column names:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\myFile.txt'
INTO TABLE `tbl_myTable`
(@var1, @var2)
SET
obj_id = @var1,
obj_geo = GeomFromText(@var2);
```

Comment: i try to create the csv from a separate program with MULTIPOLYGONS and when I import it, it generates NULL's. Can you give an example of a simple csv line?

Comment: You likely need to use the proper constructor for MySQL and MULTIPOLYGONS. Check out the MySQLdocs ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-multipolygon.html)) for that object. You will need to adapt the above example to that type, and make sure it is being stored in a Geometry column.